# Determining a cryptographic algorithm by description

Tags: cryptanalysis

I found a signing algorithm while analyzing obfuscated source code.

I only have a basic knowledge about cryptography.  I want any clue that can help me to figure out if is a known and named cryptographic algorithm or a variant, if is strong and breakable, or how the signer generates the **signature**.

The point is if this is a case of an unbreakable algorithm stop and not try anything, or continue my work trying to break.

### The Algorithm:

Having $\mathit{message}$ and $\mathit{signature}$ clearly separated in a file:

---

First calculate a $\mathit{message\_digest}$:

---

$\mathit{message\_digest} = \mathrm{padding} \mathop\Vert \operatorname{SHA-1}(\mathit{message})$

Where
$\mathrm{padding} = 0001 \mathop\Vert \mathrm{ff}(105\ \mathrm{times}) \mathop\Vert 00 = $
0001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00

---

And then check if this expression is true:

---

$\mathit{signature}^3 \equiv \mathit{message\_digest} \pmod{\mathit{key}}$

Where $\mathit{key} =$ 
C01D9FD2747B89681255F0C934610183CB45E2C57E511DBB4D651D2AD1F9B4E91D31169D3D444F91074A8EAF3F688EEC9E0E5E76F52CAF61A6ECC4A5A2154997755754E68D7C6BC1EE9C2B64B03C3157E83242A8AA8311371354363FAE8D0D5C843CEB0844FB2C3C499E1C41313A729000550038363AEF2BF8E20346B36C6B65

---

I have also found the follow signed message in the source code that I analise:

For a **message** that i know  with $\mathit{message\_digest} = $
1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF008CBB319AB06BA3F4E05625984ED2D89E42C51813

The $\mathit{signature}\ =$
5D3C1672CC314D8E50D302790D3BE9FB0CC5286A0D050BD83EA920B0F90C8E86A95E471CD34C3F81DDA89A14DE03781266F623975BD8B9CB95608EAFDE8426A7E0AEFA60DD80E76A652397D466674E439EADB30103F9A15F4EE6022DFCB8D36CBFABE1D922BBE5C7011242AE5DBAB7A35BF7C970BB1B45563176A5CFE3CBC23A

Comment: This looks like RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature with 1024-bit modulus, exponent 3, and hash SHA-1.  It's vulnerable to collisions in SHA-1, which are readily available today, if you can persuade the signer to sign certain messages of your choice: find a collision $m_0 \ne m_1$ where $m_0$ looks innocuous, persuade the signer to sign $m_0$, and now you have a signature for $m_1$.  If the verifier doesn't check the padding, then you can also use real number cube roots to forge signatures with [Bleichenbacher's attack](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/sigflaw.pdf).

Comment: I only have a signature from one mesage only is in the same source code

Comment: For this system, having one (or even a large number) of known good signatures isn't any help in breaking it.  The best known attacks are a) factoring the modulus (which you don't need any signatures for), or b) finding two messages that have a common SHA1 hash, and getting one of them signed (which doesn't look like is feasible in your case)

Comment: OK know i undertain thanks   @Squeamish Ossifrage you may do a anwer to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-8.2) with 1024-bit modulus, exponent 3, and hash SHA-1.

The signer almost certainly knows a pair of 512-bit primes $p$ and $q$ such that what you called $\mathit{key}$ is the product $p\cdot q$, conventionally called $n$.  The signer almost certainly also knows an integer $d$ solving $$3d \equiv 1 \pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p - 1, q - 1)},$$ with which they can compute cube roots modulo $n$, because $$(m^d)^3 \equiv m^{3d} \equiv m \pmod n$$ by [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Carmichael.27s_theorem) since $\lambda(n) = \lambda(p\cdot q) = \operatorname{lcm}(p - 1, q - 1)$.  Or at least the signer knows two integers
\begin{align*}
  d_p &\equiv d \pmod{p - 1} \\
  d_q &\equiv d \pmod{q - 1}
\end{align*}
with which they can compute $m^d \bmod{p\cdot q}$ in parts using the Chinese remainder theorem.

- It's vulnerable to collisions in SHA-1, which are readily available today, if you can persuade the signer to sign certain messages of your choice:

  1. Find a collision $m_0 \ne m_1$ with $\operatorname{SHA-1}(m_0) = \operatorname{SHA-1}(m_1)$ where $m_0$ looks innocuous and $m_1$ is malicious.
  2. Persuade the signer to sign $m_0$.
  3. Now you have a signature for $m_1$.

Whether you can find _innocuous_ and _malicious_ values of $m_0$ and $m_1$ is not obvious, but researchers published a [standard toy collision](https://shattered.info) that you can add a common suffix to in order to make as many more collisions as you want.

- If the verifier checks only the SHA-1 hash, and doesn't check the padding, then you can use real number cube roots to forge signatures with [Bleichenbacher's attack](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/sigflaw.pdf).
- The modulus can be factored by well-funded adversaries like major corporations and governments.  But you probably don't have enough money for that, unless it turns out to be a multiprime modulus—it's possible, but unlikely, that $\mathit{key}$ has factorization into smaller primes $p_1\cdot p_2 \cdots p_k$, or even prime powers $p_1^{e_1} \cdot p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$, in which case factoring it may be feasible even for a poor soul who can't afford a cryptanalyst beyond crypto.se.

Answer (score 3):

It's RSA signature validation, using the PKCS-1.5 signature padding, with $e=3$, and the RSA modulus given by $\mathit{key}$.

It's a circa 1024 bit key; assuming $\mathit{key}$ is a properly chosen RSA modulus, nowadays it would be considered potentially breakable (in the sense that you could recover the private key, and hence be able to sign any message you want), however it would be a major effort.

If you're asking whether you can trust it, well, probably not; a well funded adversary could likely break it.  If you're asking whether you can break it, well, no; you're not a well funded adversary.